# File Download issue in FireFox only

Tags: c#, cross-browser, http-headers

I have make a messaging system in which user can send messages to each other, they can also send files as attachement in message(its like simple email system).
I am facing an issue in firefox, if file name contains space(eg 602_Sign File for ticket.doc)
in firefox it'll save with  602_Sign.doc however it should display complete name,issue is working fine on IE and chrome,below is my code for downloading file

```
public ActionResult Download(string attFileName)
        {
            string FileName = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/MessageAttachmentFiles"), attFileName);
            System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
            response.ClearContent();
            response.Clear();
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename = {0}", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FileName)));
            response.TransmitFile(FileName);
            response.Flush();
            response.End();
            return null;

        }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The below should work

```
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", 
                    string.Format("attachment; filename = \"{0}\"",
                    System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FileName)));
```

More details on why http://kb.mozillazine.org/Filenames_with_spaces_are_truncated_upon_download

Comment: Please note that Filename is encapsulated within double quote. Which will ensure the file name is properly sent.

Comment: Thank you, 

Adding \"{0}\" fixed it on Firefox. Note: it was good with Chrome and IE.

My Code as Example (I hope it help):
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",string.Format("attachment;filename=\"{0}\"",Path.GetFileName(filePath)));

Answer (score 3):

the filename should be surrounded by double quotes

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="602_Sign File for ticket.doc"
```

Comment: `Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "\"" + stringFileName + "\"");`

Answer (score 0):

```
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", 
                    string.Format("attachment; filename = \"{0}\"",
                    System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FileName)));
```

This is the right solution