# Why does Firefox trim the response file name?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, firefox

The following code accesses a helper method which creates and returns an EPPlus ExcelPackage, then returns the package to the browser:

```
public ActionResult DownloadMatrixExcel(int projectId)
        {
            try
            {
                // Get project details
                var project = (from p in db.Projects
                               where p.ProjectId == projectId
                               select new
                               {
                                   companyName = p.Company.Name,
                                   projectName = p.Name
                               }).Single();

                // Must append file type to file download responses
                var fileName = project.projectName + "-" + project.companyName + "-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + ".xlsx";

                // Configure response
                Response.Clear();
                Response.BufferOutput = false;
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);

                // Create and populate excel package
                var matrixSpreadsheet = ExcelHelper.BuildMatrixExcel(projectId);
                matrixSpreadsheet.SaveAs(Response.OutputStream);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return Content("Error: " + e.Message);
            }

            // Download okay - No ViewResult
            return new EmptyResult();
        }
```

Works fine in every browser I have tested but FireFox 18.0.1 (have yet to test other FF versions) trims the file name at the first space, so "someproject - somecompany - thedate" is just "someproject". I can do a Replace and remove spaces but this makes some file names look a bit odd. File extension seems to be intact and no other issues but wondered if anyone could offer an explanation or fix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, found the answer here while researching another issue: [File Download issue in FireFox only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024063/file-download-issue-in-firefox-only)

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", 
                    string.Format("attachment; filename = \"{0}\"",
                    System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FileName)));
```

This will also give the file the correct content type when you choose to save rather than open in browser in FireFox.

Answer (score 5):

You should place the filename between quote characters (`"filename"`).

Comment: Sorry, I guess I must misunderstand. Wouldn't that just mean the filename was a string: "fileName"?

Comment: No, I meant that in the final header, the filename should be quoted: `Content-disposition: attachment; filename="your filename here.ext"`.

Comment: Okay, I tried this: Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename='" + fileName + "'"); but just got a leading apostrophe...

Comment: `Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "\"" + stringFileName + "\"");`