# Firefox removes multiple spaces from file name

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-core, firefox, content-disposition

I am using **.NET Core 3.1** to serve the file to the user. I have the following controller code for downloading a file whose name contains multiple spaces:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadFileWithMultipleSpaces()
{
    string fileName = "file     with multiple     spaces.txt";
    string filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "AppData", fileName);
    using (FileStream stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(filePath))
    {
        Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status200OK;
        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", $"attachment; filename = \"{fileName}\"");
        await stream.CopyToAsync(Response.Body);
        await Response.CompleteAsync();
        return new EmptyResult();
    }
}
```

When I access this controller method from Chrome (84.0.4147.89), downloaded file name contains multiple spaces (`file     with multiple     spaces.txt`). However, if I try to download the file with Firefox (79.0), downloaded file name is `file with multiple spaces.txt`.

I found a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024063/file-download-issue-in-firefox-only). They suggested that file name should be wrapped in double quotes. In my case, file name is wrapped with double quotes but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Content-Disposition just advises the browser. You can't assume that it won't sanitize the name.

Comment: You can replace " " with "&nbsp;" for a non-breaking space.